# ¿Qué solución tienen a este problema?

Tags: git-push

Mi nombre es Jesús Gálvez
El problema es que hace poco le preste a un compañero (luis-ronaldo) mi laptop para que clonara su repositorio e hiciera los cambios y pues finalmente el push a la rama master.
Después de ello, y a pesar de que cerre cesión en el navegador de su cuenta en GitHub y borrar su usuario en Git de mi laptop, aun me solicita los permisos de su cuenta para hacer el push a al rama donde nos solicitan mandar los cambios.
Les dejo unas pequeñas capturas del error que me manda.
Detalle: En este momento Git no cuenta con el config de ninguna cuenta, ya que restaure y aun así sigue con ese detalle. Agradezco mucho su comprensión.
[image: Error1]
[image: Error2]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cambiar al usuario desde la consola, por ejemplo:

**git config --list** te muestra la configuración actual de tu repo

```
user.name=Aguilar
user.email=aguilar@gmail.com
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=auto
color.diff=auto
```

despues con los comandos..

**git config --global user.name "Aguilar"**

**git config --global user.email aguilar@example.com**

o puedes echarle un ojo a la documentación de git:

```
https://git-scm.com/doc
```

Comment: Ese proceso lo realice, y aun me pide dicha autorización